# Help with debugging block GMRES

Tags: iterative-method, krylov-method, gmres

I have written block version of GMRES by referring [1] and MATLAB implementation of gmres. I need to write it for complex matrices. My block implementation when run on single RHS is giving correct answer but when run with block RHS is converging but LHS is not matching. Can anyone please help me to debug or point in direction how can this be debugged? Are there any standard set of matrix and vectors where intermediate vectors like Krylov subspace basis or H matrix are know (or can be easily computed)?

[1] Iterative Methods for Sparse Linear Systems, Saad Yousef

Pasting here my blockGMRES and wrapper testcode I am using.

```
function [x, error, iter, flag] = myblockgmres1( A, x, b, max_it, tol )

% input   A        complex nonsymmetric positive definite matrix
%         x        complex initial guess vector block
%         b        complex right hand side vector block
%         max_it   INTEGER maximum number of iterations
%         tol      complex error tolerance
%
% output  x        complex solution vector block
%         error    real error norm
%         iter     INTEGER number of iterations performed
%         flag     INTEGER: 0 = solution found to tolerance
%                           1 = no convergence given max_it

   iter = 0;                                         
   flag = 0;
   numRHS = min(size(b));
   
   bnrm2 = norm( b );
   if  ( bnrm2 == 0.0 ), bnrm2 = 1.0; end

   r =  b-A*x ;
   error = norm( r ) / bnrm2;
   if ( error < tol ) return, end

   [n,n] = size(A);                                  
   m = max_it;
   p = numRHS;
   V(1:n, 1:numRHS) = zeros(n,numRHS);
   H = [];
   QH = [];
   cs = [];
   sn = [];
   e1 = zeros(n, numRHS);
   for i=1:numRHS
    e1(i,i) = 1 + 0i;    
   end

   r = b-A*x;
   %calculate QR of initial residue r0
   [r0,R] = qr(r, 0);
   V(:,1:numRHS) = r0(:,1:numRHS);
   g = e1*R(1:numRHS, 1:numRHS);
    
     for j = 1:max_it,
         Avj = A*V(:,(j-1)*p+1:j*p);
         for i = 1:j
             H((i-1)*p+1:i*p, (j-1)*p+1:j*p) = V(:,(i-1)*p+1:i*p)'*Avj;
             Avj = Avj - V(:,(i-1)*p+1:i*p)*H((i-1)*p+1:i*p, (j-1)*p+1:j*p);
         end
         [Q2, R2] = qr(Avj, 0); 
         H(j*p+1:(j+1)*p, (j-1)*p+1:j*p) = R2(1:numRHS, 1:numRHS);
         V(:, j*p+1:(j+1)*p) = Q2(:, 1:numRHS);
         %QH is H which gets reduced through Given's
         QH = [QH; zeros(p, (j-1)*p)];
         QH = [QH zeros((j+1)*p, p)];
         QH(:, (j-1)*p+1:j*p) = H(:, (j-1)*p+1:j*p);
         
         %apply Givens rotation in all previous iterations
         %to new block of columns
         for k = (j-1)*p+1:j*p
             %columns-wise
             for l = 1:k-1
                %reverse order of rows in that block
                for i = p:-1:1
                        % apply Givens rotation
                        col = k;
                        row1 = l + i - 1;
                        row2 = l + i;
                        rr = QH(row1, col);
                        hh = QH(row2, col);
                        QH(row1, col)  = cs(l, i)*rr - sn(l, i)*hh;
                        QH(row2, col) = conj(sn(l, i))*rr + cs(l, i)*hh;
                end
             end
             %new column reduction
             for i = p:-1:1
                col = k;
                l = k;
                row1 = l + i - 1;
                row2 = l + i;
                rr = QH(row1, col);
                hh = QH(row2, col);
                rnorm = norm(rr);
                hnorm = norm(hh);
                rhnorm = sqrt(rnorm*rnorm + hnorm*hnorm);
                sn(l, i) =  -1*(hh*rr) / (rnorm*rhnorm);
                cs(l, i) =  real(rnorm/rhnorm);
                temp = conj(sn(l, i))*g(row1, :) + cs(l, i)*g(row2, :);
                g(row1, :) = g(row1, :)*cs(l, i) + sn(l, i)*g(row2, :);
                g(row2, :) = temp;
                QH(row1, col) = cs(l, i)*rr - sn(l, i)*hh;
                QH(row2, col) = 0.0;
             end
         end
         'iter=', j
         noexit = 0;
         %F-norm
         for i=1:numRHS
             error(i)  = norm(g(j*p+1:(j+1)*p, i));
         end
         norm(error)
         if(norm(error) > tol)
           noexit = 1;
         end
         %solve triangular systtem
         if ( noexit == 0 || j == max_it),  
            y = zeros(size(b));
            y = QH(1:j*p,1:j*p) \ g(1:j*p,:);
            %y = y*norm(b);
            y1(1:j*p, :) = y(1:j*p, :);
            x = x + V(:,1:j*p)*y1;
            break;
         end
     end

   if ( error > tol ) flag = 1; end;
```

Testcode to run blockgmres, here you can replace A, RHS and LHS with your test matrices and vectors. If required I can attach test matrix and vector I am using.

````
clear all;
A = dlmread('SystemMatrix_1.00e+006_real.txt') + 1i*dlmread('SystemMatrix_1.00e+006_imag.txt');
RHS1 = dlmread('System_1.00e+006_RHS_block1_real.txt') + 1i*dlmread('System_1.00e+006_RHS_block1_imag.txt') ;
RHS0 = dlmread('System_1.00e+006_RHS_block0_real.txt') + 1i*dlmread('System_1.00e+006_RHS_block0_imag.txt') ;

LHS0 = zeros(size(RHS0));
LHS1 = zeros(size(RHS0));
LHS0_ = dlmread('System_1.00e+006_LHS_block0_real.txt') + 1i*dlmread('System_1.00e+006_LHS_block0_imag.txt') ;
LHS1_ = dlmread('System_1.00e+006_LHS_block1_real.txt') + 1i*dlmread('System_1.00e+006_LHS_block1_imag.txt') ;

err = 0;
iter = 0;

%[LHS0,flag,relres,iter,resvec] = gmres(A, RHS0, length(RHS0), 1e-4);
%[LHS1,flag,relres,iter,resvec] = gmres(A, RHS1, length(RHS0), 1e-4);

%[LHS0, err, iter] = mygmres(A, LHS0, RHS0, length(RHS0), 1e-4);
%[LHS1, err, iter] = mygmres(A, LHS1, RHS1, length(RHS0), 1e-4);

%call block GMRES
LHS = [LHS0 LHS1];
RHS = [RHS0 RHS1];
%[LHS0, err, iter] = myblockgmres1(A, LHS(:,1), RHS(:,1), length(RHS0), 1e-4);
%[LHS1, err, iter] = myblockgmres1(A, LHS(:,2), RHS(:,2), length(RHS0), 1e-4);
[LHS, err, iter] = myblockgmres1(A, LHS, RHS, length(RHS0), 1e-4);
LHS0 = LHS(:,1);
LHS1 = LHS(:,2);

close all
plot(abs(LHS0_))
hold on
plot(abs(LHS0))
legend('expected LHS0','LHS0')
fprintf('relative error = %f\n', norm(LHS0-LHS0_)/norm(LHS0_))
fprintf('relative error = %f\n', norm(LHS1-LHS1_)/norm(LHS1_))
```
````

Comment: This is the wrong forum. You can't expect to dump 100 lines of code without documentation on us and help you find your bugs I'm afraid.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about debugging a piece of code, not a CS&E question.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I think there is a constructive part of the question here: regarding the question on how to debug (debug directions) and reference for standard sets with known values.

But I agree, this is....a bit above minimum example...

Comment: Thanks Anton for showing positive part. Definitely I am not asking for 'give me working code' but couldn't figure out better way of asking help without giving code. Just a direction on how such problems can be debugged will help as I am little clueless here. I will improve the documentation part of code, thanks anyway for looking at question.